# Why don't compound assignment or iterative operators work on dereferenced pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I want to increment a pointer that's referencing a the location of an `int` I can't use these methods:

```
 *Pntr +=1;
 *Pntr++;
```

However, using this method works with no problems:

```
 *Pntr = *Pntr + 1;
```

What's happening that causes these shorthand methods not to work. (Also must point out I'm using Visual Studio and it acts weird at times so I think I should mention that)

Comment: What prevents you from using `*Pntr +=1;`? It should behave identically to `*Pntr = *Pntr + 1;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I want to **increment a pointer** that's referencing a the location of an int... *[emphasis added]*

Note that when you increment a pointer, **it gets incremented in steps of the object size that the pointer can point to**.

Since you have mentioned -

> using this method works with no problems:
>
> `*Pntr = *Pntr + 1;`

So, it looks like you want to increase the value at location, pointed by `Pntr`, by `1`.

The precedence of postfix `++` operator is higher than unary `*` operator (check [**operator precedence**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table). So, the expression

```
*Pntr++;
```

will be evaluated as

```
*(Pntr++);
```

which will move the pointer `Pntr` by size of `int` and then dereference it.
To increment the value of pointer, you can do:

```
(*Pntr)++;
```

You can also use the prefix `++` operator:

```
++*Pntr;
```

The expression

```
*Pntr +=1;
```

is same as

```
*Pntr = *Pntr + 1;
```

and both will increase the value at location pointed by `Pntr` by `1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
*Pntr +=1;
```

This increments the value the pointer is pointing to.

```
*Pntr++;
```

This is the same as:

```
*(Pntr++);
```

Which increments the pointer, dereferences the original value of the pointer, and discards the retrieved value.

```
 *Pntr = *Pntr + 1;
```

This, like the first line, increments the value the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: And, of course, this is all about "operator precedence", in case the OP wants to put a searchable name on it.